# Is it an applet or plugin or widget

Tags: panel, plugins, applet

I have installed Ubuntu recently, and I have a question about the applications on the side-panel. Are the programs that run in or on the panel (such as clock or volume) called applets or plugins or a widget?

Comment: Usually applets, but you are welcome to call them anything.

Comment: Lxpanel refers to them as plugins in `~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/panel`. XFCE seems to prefer `plugin` as well. Look at the rest and see what they're called.

Comment: David Cole I'm not sure why the edit as I had to d/l and install all of those desktop environments.  If there is no explanation there can be no improvement.  That creates a one-way street.  Feel free to PM me as I am unable at the moment to read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

As found on [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Applets):

> Applets are icons that reside in your panels for launching specific applications and sometimes offering additional functionality.
>
> There are many applets available not only in the default Ubuntu installation, but some extras, also. What follows is an explanation of how to use applets and an alphabetical list of the key ones that are available in Ubuntu.

As stated by mikewhatever, you are free to call them what you want, however Ubuntu officially refers to them as Applets.